# Where does Ubuntu 7.10 store the wallpaper filename?

Tags: ubuntu

I re-installed my girlfriend's laptop, and upgraded Ubuntu from 7.10 to 9.04.

Now I want to re-install her original desktop wallpaper, but I don't know the name of the picture she had selected.

So where does Ubuntu 7.10 store that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can find it somewhere in the `gconf-editor`.  Just press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>, run `gconf-editor` and browse to `/desktop/gnome/background`.  There should be something in there that can help you out.  Be careful with it though, you can botch your gnome configuration if you mess around too much.

Comment: Thanks tj111, found it in $HOME/.gconf/desktop/gnome/background/%gconf.xml